# why Wine can not find file in app folder

Tags: wine

Trying to run an app in app folder with this command:

```
 wine file.exe
```

results in this error message:

```
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\file.exe"
```

Why do I get this error message?

Comment: Do `wine ./file.exe` or `wine /path/to/file.exe` work?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to run a file located in your home directory or your desktop? If so, wine can't locate it because it's outside its own directory structure.

Try this:

Copy file.exe to the default wine installation:

```
cp file.exe $HOME/.wine/drive_c/
```

Execute that file:

```
wine $HOME/.wine/drive_c/file.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

in .wine drive c:\windows\Program Files (resp Program Files x86 for 32 bit) create a softlink to the directory containing your program and start it from the program directory with wine. it works fine. tried that with several programs which are able to run under wine.