# Wine post installation errors in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, wine

I have tried to install wine stable in ubuntu. When I ran the command `wine -version` it showed me the errors below in terminal:

```
imon@imon-hp-probook-4410s:~$ wine –version
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/imon/.wine'
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0012:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0012:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0012:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0014:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0014:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0014:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
wine: configuration in L"/home/imon/.wine" has been updated.
0009:err:module:__wine_process_init L"C:\\windows\\system32\\\2013version.exe" not found
imon@imon-hp-probook-4410s:~$ wine –version
0009:err:module:__wine_process_init L"C:\\windows\\system32\\\2013version.exe" not found
imon@imon-hp-probook-4410s:~$ wine -version
0009:err:module:__wine_process_init L"C:\\windows\\system32\\-version.exe" not found
```

I also attached the full log of the installation process and the command I tried afterwards (the installation log itself is hundreds lines long and has no errors):
[Wine installation error](https://pastebin.com/CgwqivfW)

What seems to be the problem, and what do the errors say?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why Wine can not find file in app folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/582557/why-wine-can-not-find-file-in-app-folder)

Comment: @LinuxSurfaceNut    No, I want to solve the errors that I have provided. please check the provided link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like those are not post installation errors, but more of a command input error.
Yes, the first few logs may be a little confusing when running `wine -version`, but they are not actually related to your command directly, and rather address the initial configuration set up of the newly installed Wine program and its errors.

Those could have happened even if you would try to run a built-in `system32` program such as `notepad.exe` or `ping.exe`.

**You must have also stumbled upon this prompt**:
[image: prompt]

Notice the error outputs you receive when trying to execute the command `wine -version` again:

```
imon@imon-hp-probook-4410s:~$ wine –version
0009:err:module:__wine_process_init L"C:\\windows\\system32\\\2013version.exe" not found
imon@imon-hp-probook-4410s:~$ wine -version
0009:err:module:__wine_process_init L"C:\\windows\\system32\\-version.exe" not found
```

Wine is trying to find a program with the name `-version.exe`, and this is due to a wrong syntax you've typed.

From the [wine manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wine):

```
Name
wine - run Windows programs on Unix
Synopsis
wine program [arguments ... ]
wine --help
wine --version
For instructions on passing arguments to Windows programs, please see the PROGRAM/ARGUMENTS section of the man page.
```

Wine takes only two types of input structures: **a program name** and optional arguments for it, or **internal wine flags** which begin with the `--` string: `--help` and `--version`.

To sum things up: if you would like to check your wine version, please use `wine --version`.

Comment: Thank you for helping me to solve this issue